# MySQL combining several select statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Wondering how/if I can combine the two select statements.

```
        $searchCat = $mysqli->query("SELECT category_id, category.name FROM category WHERE category.name = '$searchTerm'");

    while ($r=$searchCat->fetch_assoc()) {
        $category_id=$r["category_id"];

        $searchBus = $mysqli->query("SELECT business.name, business.street FROM business WHERE business.category_id = '$category_id'");             

        while ($r=$searchBus->fetch_assoc()) {
            $name=$r["name"];
            $street=$r["street"];

            echo "$name, $street<br>";
        }
    } // end of while
```

For output I only need the data from the Business table, the 1st select finds the correlating ID of the searched term, that Id is also housed in the Business table.

So can I do a join or union where the 1st select gets the id and then it is passed to the 2nd Select allowing me to skip the 1st While?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it into single query too.

```
$query = "SELECT `business`.`name`, `business`.`street` 
          FROM `business`, `category` 
          WHERE 
             `business`.`category_id` = `category`.`category_id` 
              AND 
             `category`.`name` = '$searchTerm'";

$searchBus = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: Thanks! The `category`.`name` = '$searchTerm' bit was throwing me

Comment: It Worked or Not? @harkly

Comment: Sorry, it did. I've been playing around with it.

Comment: Good *Keep Coding* @harkly

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT category_id, category.name 
FROM category c inner join business b using (category_id) 
WHERE category.name = {Term}
```

Please escape your queries though its currently open to SQL injection

Comment: Thanks! I will escape then once I have everything figured out and working

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `exists` operator:

```sql
SELECT business.name, business.street 
FROM   business
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   category
               WHERE  category.name = '$searchTerm' AND
                      category.category_id = business.category_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT business.name, business.street, category.name
FROM business 
JOIN category ON category.category_id = business.category_id
WHERE category.name = '$searchTerm'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT business.name, business.street 
FROM category c, business b
WHERE c.category_id = b.category_id and c.name = '$searchTerm'
```